# How to call MainActivity method from non-Activity class?

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble on a runtime permission method in a non-activity class. I want to call a public `MainActivity` method to a helper class.

`MainActivity.java` method:

```
public void a() {
    //some method
}
```

Now my helper class:

```
Class B {
    private Context mContext;
    public B(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        //now I am calling Mainactivity Method
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.a(); 
    }
}
```

Calling class B from CActivity:

```
onCreate() {
    B b = new B(this);
}
```

But it gives me a runtime error.

**UPDATE:**

My method has a runtime permission method which isn't static. Ex- `requestPermissions(), onRequestPermissionsResult()`.

Comment: paste your error (logcat)

Comment: You can use interface.

Comment: You should not create instances of your activities

Comment: Can you give us the goal of this this construct and replace "B" and "a" with more semantic-meaningfull names so that we can understand why you want to let B call MainActivity.a?

Comment: Here is my previous question. I didn't find answer. I am creating a speerate Location class in that question. This question was related  to previous questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662822/android-fusedlocation-runtime-permission-from-mainactivity

Answer (score 0):

Make that method as static so you can call without creating the class object

eg

```
public static void testing() {}
```

now calling

```
MainActivity.testing();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a good idea to construct activity directly. If you want to signal the activity to do some task for your helper class (Class B), you better [implement interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941960/how-to-implement-a-listener) for listening or simply use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library

If you really want to make your method work, rather than instantiating the Activity again in B class's constructor can you pass your activity as a parameter to B class? (I am not sure it would work)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put `B b = new B(this);` because you're instantiating another class.

Instead, use `getActivity() or getContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove class B. and call A activity's method directly in C activity.

Extend your C activity with A activity like this:

```
public class C extends A{
...
}
```

Then in C activity call A activity's method like below:

```
C.super.requestAppPermissions();
```

Hope it will help you.